# Rails - creating "huge" XML file on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

Once a month I need to create almost 40MB XML file in my Rails app and save this file. As a storage I use Amazon S3 platform. When I do this task on my localhost (Webrick server), this task takes like 5 minutes => the file is saved in the Amazon's bucket. All are happy.

But when I run this task on Heroku, the app is not responding like 45 minutes and the file is not saved in Amazon.

I know heroku allows to run a task for just 30 seconds, but after this time is displayed an error message and the task is running in the background. While this operation is the app "idle".

But, how is possible that the file is not created and saved? Is there any limitation on Heroku for file transfer or something like that?

I spent whole afternoon with searching the problem, but until now without success.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us how you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the process is killed after 30 seconds, not running in the background as you suggest.  Use delayed_job to get backgrounding as detailed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job.  If you have a single method that creates and transfers your file you can just use delayed_job's delay method on that.  Note that a delayed_job spins up its own little environment.  So in my case, I write the file to tmp and then transfer that to S3 and note that all has to be done in the same job because when the first job is done that tmp directory evaporates.